# docker-compose up and user inputs on stdin

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, stdin

Can someone explain (and maybe give a workaround) for the following behavior of docker-compose ?

Given the following files :

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.8

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

until [ ! -z "$PLOP" ]; do
    echo -n 'enter value here: '
    read PLOP
done

echo "Good ... PLOP is $PLOP"

exit 1
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  plop:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    image: webofmars/plop:latest
```

The output will be the following:

1) `./entrypoint.sh`

```
docker-stdin> ./entrypoint.sh
enter value here:
CASE1
Good ... PLOP is CASE1
```

Which seems **OK**

2) `docker-stdin> docker run -it webofmars/plop`

```
enter value here: CASE2
Good ... PLOP is CASE2
```

Which seems **OK**

3) `docker-stdin> docker-compose run plop`

```
enter value here: CASE3
Good ... PLOP is CASE3
```

Which seems **OK**

4) `docker-stdin> docker-compose up`

```
Recreating docker-stdin_plop_1 ... done
Attaching to docker-stdin_plop_1 (last forever)
```

Which seems quite odd and **NOT OK** for my use case

Did i missed something ?

Answer (score 31):

[docker compose up and user inputs on stdin](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3081)

> That is expected behaviour. up is not interactive. It can start
>   multiple containers, so you can't have a single terminal that has
>   stdin open for multiple containers.

But there is option to you can do with docker-compose.

Attach in different window, when you start with docker-compose up, you can add -d parameter and it will start that docker in background.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Then just attach that docker and enter value

```
docker attach play_001_plop_1
```

Single line command:

```
docker-compose up -d && docker attach play_001_plop_1
```

Comment: Ok indeed i understand that up is not aimed to be interactive but the workaround will not work because the docker-compose file is supposed to be run by an orchestrator (rancher 1.6) and such a behavior is not under our control. So i guess this is something we should remenber never do interactive containers, you should rely on ENV vars. Then the question is still interresting for legacy app that you don't want to change.