# Why does the following docker-compose execution exit without waiting for user input?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

When I run the following simple Node.js code (index.js) using Docker, the code executes as expected - waiting for user input. But when I run the same code using Docker-Compose, Node.js exits before waiting for user input.

I've been able to run the Node application using the Dockerfile, but not Docker-Compose

Here is the index.js file that I'm able to run in the Dockerfile (but not Docker-Compose):

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

readline.question(`What's your name? `, (name) => {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`)
  readline.close()
});
```

And the Dockerfile I used:

````
FROM node:12.2

ENV NODE_ENV=development
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

WORKDIR /app/src
CMD ["node", "index.js"]


As with the Dockerfile experience:

```shell
$ docker build -t commandline .
...
$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/src:/app/src commandline
What's your name? Scott
Hi Scott!
````

I expected the Docker-Compose version to execute the same way, but it exits the Node and Docker process before the user has an opportunity to respond:

```sh
$ docker-compose up
Creating mega_node_1 ... done
Attaching to mega_node_1
node_1  | What's your name? mega_node_1 exited with code 0
$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose up and user inputs on stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106678/docker-compose-up-and-user-inputs-on-stdin)

Comment: Following suggestions on the possible duplicate, I tried:
```
$ docker-compose run scottfred/megastack
ERROR: No such service: scottfred/megastack
```
So, this doesn't work

Comment: Do you name your service "scottfred/megastack" in docker-compose.yml? Isn't it the image name?

Comment: Ugh... you're right... thanks!  I misunderstood the "docker run" option.  It works when I use "docker-compose run node", where "node" is the service name in my docker-compose.yml file.  Thanks!