# Start an interactive node.js CLI app with docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

I made a node.js interactive CLI app to let communicate our intern work log with jira.
It works without problems, but I want to make it cross platform using docker.

The idea is to start docker and start inside the container the CLI, and than close the CLI and close also the container.

Now, to start my app I just give `npm start`. I managed to create a docker container and run the app inside, but to start the app I have to `docker-compose exec app bash` and then `npm start`

I want to do it during the container start up process, in order to give just `docker-compose up` and start to use my CLI.

Is that in any way possible?

I tried to add `commands: "bash -c npm start"` to my docker-compose file, and it works, but the output is not interactive. I see my app in the docker log but I can not interact with it.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you ask your end user to install Node instead of installing Docker, and to run `npm start` instead of `sudo docker-compose ...`?  I'm not clear I see the benefit of Docker here.

Comment: [docker-compose up and user inputs on stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106678/docker-compose-up-and-user-inputs-on-stdin) describes a workaround for it, but this isn't a case Compose is especially designed for.

Comment: @DavidMaze Everybody in the company has Docker but not everybody has Node.